# packaged_task example problem? Stroustrup example modification

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to modify the example given in Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 122 to call the accumulator() function directly with iterators.  Specifically remove use of *double and use iterators.

So far, I have this, however it has compilation problems which I don't understand.

Does anyone have any pointers on accomplishing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

double comp2(vector<double>& v) {
  using Task_type = double(vector<double>::iterator,
               vector<double>::iterator, double);

  packaged_task<Task_type> pt0 {accumulate};
  packaged_task<Task_type> pt1 {accumulate};

#if 0
  future<double> f0 {pt0.get_future()};
  future<double> f1 {pt1.get_future()};

  double *first = &v[0];
  // move required bc package_task cannot be copied
  thread t1 {move(pt0), first, first + v.size()/2, 0};
  thread t2 {move(pt1), first + v.size()/2, first + v.size(), 0};

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  return f0.get() + f1.get();
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<double> v = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

  cout << "v: " << comp2(v) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and the error is:

```
g++ -lpthread -pedantic -Wall test87.cc && ./a.out
test87.cc: In function ‘double comp2(std::vector<double>&)’:
test87.cc:13:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::packaged_task<double(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >, double)>::packaged_task(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   packaged_task<Task_type> pt0 {accumulate};
                                           ^
In file included from test87.cc:6:
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1528:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Allocator> std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::packaged_task(std::allocator_arg_t, const _Allocator&, std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&)’
  packaged_task(allocator_arg_t, const _Allocator&,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/future:1528:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test87.cc:13:43: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
   packaged_task<Task_type> pt0 {accumulate};
```

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is not a function, it's a function template. To construct the `packaged_task`, you need to pass it a concrete function, like this:

```
packaged_task<Task_type> pt0 {accumulate<vector<double>::iterator, double>};
packaged_task<Task_type> pt1 {accumulate<vector<double>::iterator, double>};
```

You should also make `first` an iterator instead of a pointer, since it's not guaranteed that an iterator is implemented as a pointer.

```
auto first = v.begin();
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/RgwLwU).